# 404 error on step 2 of wordpress config: Azure, nginx, wordpress 6, php 8

Tags: wordpress, nginx

placed all WordPress files in /site/wwwroot go to the URL in a browser and wp-admin/setup-config.php starts. I select language, input external database info, then get a 404 error when trying to load //wp0admin/setup-config.php?step=2

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual config file of ngnix you have to add following line into location.

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: What was the error you are getting